# Create product programmatically

Tags: commerce

I have a product with a custom field, according to [this](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/3315/creating-product-programmatically). I know I can create product with

```
$cp = commerce_product_new('product');
$cp->is_new = TRUE;
$cp->revision_id = NULL;
$cp->uid = 1;
$cp->status = 1;
$cp->created = $cp->changed = time();
$cp->sku = $product[sku];
$cp->title = $product[name];
$cp->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$cp->commerce_price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array(
 'amount' => $product[sale_price] ? $product[sale_price] : $product[retail_price],
 'currency_code' => 'USD',
)));$product[retail_price];
commerce_product_save($cp);
```

but I have some custom field.

How can I create a Drupal Commerce product programmatically with full custom fields?

Is  `$cp->myfield1='22';` sufficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A commerce product is an entity like any other, so...

```
$cp->field_my_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = '22';
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a tweak: the create method on the product controller already has some defaults so no need to add things like is_new or status.

```
  public function create(array $values = array()) {
    $values += array(
      'product_id' => NULL,
      'is_new' => TRUE,
      'sku' => '',
      'revision_id' => NULL,
      'title' => '',
      'uid' => '',
      'status' => 1,
      'created' => '',
      'changed' => '',
    );

    return parent::create($values);
  }
```

So I'd just do:

```
$cp = commerce_product_new('product');
$cp->uid = 1;
$cp->sku = $product[sku];
$cp->title = $product[name];
$cp->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$cp->commerce_price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array(
 'amount' => $product[sale_price] ? $product[sale_price] : $product[retail_price],
 'currency_code' => 'USD',
)));$product[retail_price];
$cp->my_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 22;
commerce_product_save($cp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my code was correct and I achieve it by  note that clive mention me, tnx for spend time

Comment: Just left it here in case someone else bumps into this :). You could mark Clive's answer as accepted for clarity.